# Pass dynamic parameters in the keyvalue (message key) to package.properties

Tags: struts2, resourcebundle

I have tried to pass dynamic parameters to `keyvalue(message to display)` which I will get from `package.properties` to the `Action` class through the `getText()` method. To get the message, we can use `getText(String keyvalue)` method. What should I do to pass some parameters and retrieve the parameters with the message through the `getText()` method?

I saw some API's to pass dynamic parameters. But I don't know how to use, these are the following API's, click [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ActionSupport.html) to see the Struts 2 API Documentation.

1. `getText(String aTextName, List<Object> args)`
2. `getText(String key, String[] args)`
3. `getText(String key, String defaultValue, String[] args)`

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose that you have following properties in your `package.properties`

1. `username.required=user name is required`
2. `password.required=password is required`

you can use `getText()` as

```
getText("username.required")
getText("password.required")
```

Now if we want to use `getText(String key, String[] args)` we have to pass following parameters

`aTextName -` the resource bundle key that is to be searched for

`args -` a list args to be used in a MessageFormat message

That means the message format pattern and other static strings will, of course, be obtained from resource bundles. Other parameters will be dynamically determined at runtime.
example
we have following entry in resource file

```
disk.data=The disk \"{0}\" artist name is {1}.
```

in this `{1}` and `{0}` are the dynamic parameters and will be determined at run time so `args` will contain the value of these parameters.

```
String artistName= demo;
 String diskName = "Artist";
 String[] testArgs = {artistName, diskName};
```

So final call will be `getText(disk.data, testArgs);`
and it will show

```
The disk demo artist name is Artist.
```

Please go through [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) to know how this work

Comment: Thank you Umesh. Helpful post.